# Injective Functions and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

1. Find the number of injective functions $f:A \rightarrow A$ where $f[\{1,2\}]=\{1,2\}$ and $f[\{3,4\}]=\{3,4\}$
2. Find the number of all functions $f:A \rightarrow A$ where $f[\{1,2\}]=\{1,2\}$ and $f[\{3,4\}]=\{3,4\}$
3. Find the number of all functions $f:A\rightarrow A$ where $f[\{1,2\}] \neq \{1,2\}$, $f[\{3,4\}] \neq \{3,4\}$, $f[\{5,26\}] \neq \{5,6\}$, $f[\{7,8\}] \neq \{7,8\}$

Please help I didn't understand this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of question is just standard combinatorics, but the talk of functions make it more intimidating. A function is just something that takes $a$ from domain and makes it to be $f(a)$ element of the codomain. Now, you have function with finite domain $\{1,2\dots, 8\}$ and this is also codomain so you can look at it this way:

*You have eight positions. In how many ways can you put a number from $\{1,2\dots, 8\}$ to each position, such that it satisfies some extra properties*.

I will do the first of the three questions in more detail:

First, if you have *any* $F: A\mapsto A$ for $A$ finite, then *f is injective if and only if it is surjective if and only if it is bijective*.  One learns that injective does not imply surjective and vice versa but that is just because you usually have functions over real numbers (or any other infinite domain). I recommend proving this equivalence for finite $A$, it is a good exercise and also a useful principle to know.

So now, we know that in the first question, $f: A\to A$ is bijective. But that means it is a permutation!

So you only need to found number of permutation (standard combinatorics problem) on eight element set, such that $1,2$ maps to $1,2$ and $3,4$ maps to $3,4$ and consequently $5,6,7,8$ mapsto $5,6,7,8$.

So by the product rule number of possible functions is $2! \cdot 2! \cdot 4!=2\cdot2\cdot24=96$.